# Adobe FLASH AS3 textfield change color

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, append, adobe, textfield

I am working an IOS app in Adobe Flash... I am trying to change the color of the textfield. I got the method for changing the text color

```
myTextP1.setTextFormat(format,0,24);
```

This is working perfectly also the color of text changed from the forst charcter to 25th character... But my problem is I need to change color of the appended text.. for example my text is "I am Jocheved " and I am appending the text with "Jocheved is a good man" so if I am giving 0 -3 then from the first text the color is changing I need to change the first character of the appended text not from the beginning.. instead of counting the text till the appended text is there any other method to change the color.

```
var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
            format.font = "Verdana"; 
            format.color = 0xFF0000; 
            format.size = 23;

if(my369P==1)
{
    myTextPH1.text = "Strength of Mentality"
    myTextP1.text = "You have a good mind and an excellent memory. You should continue to learn and study throughout your life. You are more intellectual than emotional or practical. You may tend to look down on those who are not your intellectual equals—that could attract bad Karma!"

    if(my258P==1)
    {



        myTextP1.appendText("\n\nStrength of Emotionality")

        myTextP1.setTextFormat(format,0,24);
        myTextP1.appendText("\n\nYou are compassionate, understanding and emotionally balanced. You tend to achieve your goals."); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TextField.setTextFormat` only affects the characters you specify. In order to change the color for all text, you'll want to set the default text format of the `TextField`:

`myTextP1.defaultTextFormat = format;`

Conversely, you could also just set it via the `textColor` property of the `TextField`:

`myTextP1.textColor = 0xFF0000;`